# In odoo,how to click button to jump to a new link and the wizard can be closed automatically?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I defined a wizard,generally,the wizard will be automatically closed after executing the python code when we click the button. But in Python code,`return {"type": "ir.actions.act_url","url": sign_url,"target": "new"}`at the last.The wizard does not close after the link is successfully jumped.

What should I do to click button to jump to a new link and the wizard can be closed automatically?

Odoo version is 10,Python version is 2.7

Thanks everyone!

Here is my code.

wizard,`.py`file

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

class CreateAuthSignUsers(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'create.auth.sign.users'
    _description = 'Create Auth Sign Users'

    account_num = fields.Char('Account Num')

    @api.multi
    def confirm_jump_to_link(self):
        return {
            "type": "ir.actions.act_url",
            "url": 'http://192.168.43.56/v1/account/%s' % self.account_num,
            "target": "new"
        }
```

wizard,`xml`file

```xml
    <record id="sign_the_authorization_letter_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Sign Authorization Letter</field>
        <field name="model">create.auth.sign.users</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Sign Authorization Letter">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="account_num"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
                <footer>
                    <button string="Confirm" name="confirm_jump_to_link" type="object" default_focus="1" class="btn-primary"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: The way you wanted is available in Odoo higher versions . have a look https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/web_ir_actions_act_multi/ . Hope you will get a idea based on this.

Comment: @VishnuVaNnErI Thank you. I haven't found any good way to address this. If I find it, I'll be the first to post it here.